# Sync Chrome extension login with web app (Next JS)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to sync chrome extension and web app login. I'm currently using Next Auth to get the access token for a provider. Any one has experience with it ? I am able to send message from the web app to the extension with the access token, but not sure how I can authenticate the user in the extension.

Comment: Found a solution? I'm facing the same problem